# How can I force Internet Explorer to apply CSS styles

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have a couple of CSS selectors like this:

```
table.SearchCustomerResults > thead > tr > th[sortOrder="0"] {}
table.SearchCustomerResults > thead > tr > th[sortOrder="1"] {}
```

then I set the sortOrder extension attribute for each of the cells in JavaScript. However, the changed style is not visible in the browser (IE7, perhaps other) until I move the cursor a bit. How can I force styles to be re-evaluated?

Edit: I didn't use IE6 as originally stated, but IE7. The question still remains, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various hack-y ways to force re-rendering. [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us) has a method called `forceRerendering` (naturally) that looks like this:

```
someElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
someElement.removeChild(someElement.lastChild);
```

That ought to work in this case, too.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support attribute or child selectors, so this shouldn't work at all.  Are you using [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)?

---

OK, I see now.  This looks like a bug in IE (using `div` and `title` for `th` and `sortOrder` has the same problem).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      th[sortOrder="0"] {color:red}
      th[sortOrder="1"] {color:blue}
    </style>
    <script>
      function changeSortOrder() {
        // swap the orders so that blue is actually red and vice versa
        document.getElementById("hdr0").setAttribute("sortOrder","1");
        document.getElementById("hdr1").setAttribute("sortOrder","0");
        //document.getElementById("hdr0").innerHTML += "";
        //document.getElementById("hdr1").innerHTML += "";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="changeSortOrder()">
    <table class="SearchCustomerResults">
      <thead><tr>
        <th sortOrder="0" id="hdr0">red</th>
        <th sortOrder="1" id="hdr1">blue</th>
      </tr></thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The lines that modify `innerHTML` seem to work around the bug.  Can't find any references on Google, though.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was using IE7. The question still remains, though

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem: after inserting new div IE didn't apply margin.
**next code helped:**
  setTimeout(function () { newDiv.addClass('tratata').removeClass('tratata'); }, 0);   //jquery syntax